# Cannot install TightVNCServer

Tags: raspbian

I keep getting a error message here is the output for the command 'sudo apt-get install tightvncserver'

```
 pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo apt-get install tightvncserver
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  x11-xserver-utils xfonts-base
Suggested packages:
  tightvnc-java nickle cairo-5c xorg-docs-core
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  tightvncserver x11-xserver-utils xfonts-base
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 55 not upgraded.
Need to get 7,148 kB of archives.
After this operation, 10.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Get:1 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main tightvncserver ar                                                                                                                     mhf 1.3.9-6.4 [786 kB]
Get:2 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main x11-xserver-utils                                                                                                                      armhf 7.7~3 [181 kB]
Get:3 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main xfonts-base all 1                                                                                                                     :1.0.3 [6,181 kB]
Fetched 14.5 kB in 1s (9,309 B/s)
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/t/tightvnc                                                                                                                     /tightvncserver_1.3.9-6.4_armhf.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/x/x11-xser                                                                                                                     ver-utils/x11-xserver-utils_7.7~3_armhf.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/x/xfonts-b                                                                                                                     ase/xfonts-base_1.0.3_all.deb  Size mismatch
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-mis                                                                                                                     sing?
```

I can ping anything on my pi, I am sshing into it, internet works fine

EDIT:

uname -a

```
Linux raspberrypi 3.12.35+ #730 PREEMPT Fri Dec 19 18:31:24 GMT 2014 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

apt-get update

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo apt-get update
Hit http://repository.wolfram.com stable Release.gpg
Hit http://repository.wolfram.com stable Release
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org wheezy Release.gpg
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy Release.gpg
Hit http://raspberrypi.collabora.com wheezy Release.gpg
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy Release
Hit http://raspberrypi.collabora.com wheezy Release
Hit http://repository.wolfram.com stable/non-free armhf Packages
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org wheezy Release
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/main armhf Packages
Hit http://raspberrypi.collabora.com wheezy/rpi armhf Packages
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/contrib armhf Packages
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org wheezy/main armhf Packages
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/non-free armhf Packages
Ign http://repository.wolfram.com stable/non-free Translation-en_GB
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/rpi armhf Packages
Ign http://repository.wolfram.com stable/non-free Translation-en
Ign http://raspberrypi.collabora.com wheezy/rpi Translation-en_GB
Ign http://raspberrypi.collabora.com wheezy/rpi Translation-en
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org wheezy/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org wheezy/main Translation-en
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/contrib Translation-en_GB
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/main Translation-en
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/non-free Translation-en_GB
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/non-free Translation-en
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/rpi Translation-en_GB
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/rpi Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
```

apt-get upgrade

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  fake-hwclock libfm-data lxpanel omxplayer pcmanfm
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apt apt-utils bash ca-certificates cpio curl dbus dbus-x11 dosfstools file firmware-brcm80211 gnupg gpgv libapt-inst1.5 libapt-pkg-dev libapt-pkg4.12 libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls libdbus-1-3
  libflac8 libgcrypt11 libjasper1 libkeyutils1 libmagic1 libnss3 libraspberrypi-bin libraspberrypi-dev libraspberrypi-doc libraspberrypi0 libssl1.0.0 libtasn1-3 libxml2 libyaml-0-2 mime-support
  ntp openssl python-rpi.gpio python3-rpi.gpio raspberrypi-artwork raspberrypi-bootloader rsyslog sonic-pi tzdata unzip wget wpagui wpasupplicant xdg-utils xserver-common xserver-xorg-core
50 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 112 MB of archives.
After this operation, 29.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Get:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ wheezy/main firmware-brcm80211 all 0.43-1raspi [2,633 kB]
Get:2 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main bash armhf 4.2+dfsg-0.1+deb7u3 [1,443 kB]
Get:3 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main libapt-pkg-dev armhf 0.9.7.9+rpi1+deb7u7 [187 kB]
Get:4 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main libapt-inst1.5 armhf 0.9.7.9+rpi1+deb7u7 [164 kB]
Get:5 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main libapt-pkg4.12 armhf 0.9.7.9+rpi1+deb7u7 [859 kB]
Get:6 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main gpgv armhf 1.4.12-7+deb7u6 [208 kB]
Get:7 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main gnupg armhf 1.4.12-7+deb7u6 [1,902 kB]
Get:8 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main apt armhf 0.9.7.9+rpi1+deb7u7 [1,244 kB]
Get:9 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main libssl1.0.0 armhf 1.0.1e-2+rvt+deb7u13 [1,052 kB]
Get:10 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main libgcrypt11 armhf 1.5.0-5+deb7u2 [300 kB]
Get:11 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main libkeyutils1 armhf 1.5.5-3+deb7u1 [7,880 B]
Get:12 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main file armhf 5.11-2+deb7u6 [52.3 kB]
Get:13 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main libmagic1 armhf 5.11-2+deb7u6 [200 kB]
Get:14 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main libtasn1-3 armhf 2.13-2+deb7u1 [64.0 kB]
Get:15 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main libxml2 armhf 2.8.0+dfsg1-7+wheezy2 [822 kB]
Get:16 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main curl armhf 7.26.0-1+wheezy11 [268 kB]
Get:17 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main libcurl3 armhf 7.26.0-1+wheezy11 [316 kB]
Get:18 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main libcurl3-gnutls armhf 7.26.0-1+wheezy11 [307 kB]
Get:19 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ wheezy/main python-rpi.gpio armhf 0.5.8-1 [42.3 kB]
Get:20 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main libdbus-1-3 armhf 1.6.8-1+deb7u5 [154 kB]
Get:21 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main libflac8 armhf 1.2.1-6+deb7u1 [144 kB]
Get:22 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main libjasper1 armhf 1.900.1-13+deb7u2 [141 kB]
Get:23 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ wheezy/main python3-rpi.gpio armhf 0.5.8-1 [25.0 kB]
Get:24 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main libnss3 armhf 2:3.14.5-1+deb7u3 [848 kB]
Get:25 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ wheezy/main libraspberrypi-dev armhf 1.20141219-1 [770 kB]
Get:26 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main libyaml-0-2 armhf 0.1.4-2+deb7u5 [49.4 kB]
Get:27 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main ntp armhf 1:4.2.6.p5+dfsg-2+deb7u1 [524 kB]
Get:28 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main tzdata all 2014h-0wheezy1 [447 kB]
Get:29 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main apt-utils armhf 0.9.7.9+rpi1+deb7u7 [372 kB]
Get:30 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main cpio armhf 2.11+dfsg-0.1+deb7u1 [262 kB]
Get:31 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main rsyslog armhf 5.8.11-3+deb7u2 [509 kB]
Get:32 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main wget armhf 1.13.4-3+deb7u2 [754 kB]
Get:33 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main mime-support all 3.52-1+deb7u1 [35.5 kB]
Get:34 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ wheezy/main libraspberrypi-doc armhf 1.20141219-1 [31.5 MB]
Get:35 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main openssl armhf 1.0.1e-2+rvt+deb7u13 [700 kB]
Get:36 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main ca-certificates all 20130119+deb7u1 [210 kB]
Get:37 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main dbus armhf 1.6.8-1+deb7u5 [351 kB]
Get:38 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main dbus-x11 armhf 1.6.8-1+deb7u5 [58.8 kB]
Get:39 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main dosfstools armhf 3.0.13-1+rpi1 [67.4 kB]
Get:40 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main unzip armhf 6.0-8+deb7u1 [195 kB]
Get:41 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main wpasupplicant armhf 1.0-3+deb7u1 [540 kB]
Get:42 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main wpagui armhf 1.0-3+deb7u1 [359 kB]
Get:43 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main xdg-utils all 1.1.0~rc1+git20111210-6+deb7u1 [78.3 kB]
Get:44 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main xserver-common all 2:1.12.4-6+deb7u5 [1,397 kB]
Get:45 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main xserver-xorg-core armhf 2:1.12.4-6+deb7u5 [1,607 kB]
Get:46 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ wheezy/main libraspberrypi-bin armhf 1.20141219-1 [352 kB]
Get:47 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ wheezy/main libraspberrypi0 armhf 1.20141219-1 [601 kB]
Get:48 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ wheezy/main raspberrypi-bootloader armhf 1.20141219-1 [19.6 MB]
Get:49 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ wheezy/main raspberrypi-artwork all 20141115 [75.0 kB]
Get:50 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ wheezy/main sonic-pi armhf 2.2.0-1 [37.1 MB]
Fetched 93.0 MB in 2min 0s (772 kB/s)
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/b/bash/bash_4.2+dfsg-0.1+deb7u3_armhf.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apt/libapt-pkg-dev_0.9.7.9+rpi1+deb7u7_armhf.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apt/libapt-inst1.5_0.9.7.9+rpi1+deb7u7_armhf.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apt/libapt-pkg4.12_0.9.7.9+rpi1+deb7u7_armhf.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/g/gnupg/gpgv_1.4.12-7+deb7u6_armhf.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/g/gnupg/gnupg_1.4.12-7+deb7u6_armhf.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apt/apt_0.9.7.9+rpi1+deb7u7_armhf.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.0.0_1.0.1e-2+rvt+deb7u13_armhf.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/libg/libgcrypt11/libgcrypt11_1.5.0-5+deb7u2_armhf.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/k/keyutils/libkeyutils1_1.5.5-3+deb7u1_armhf.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/f/file/file_5.11-2+deb7u6_armhf.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/f/file/libmagic1_5.11-2+deb7u6_armhf.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/libt/libtasn1-3/libtasn1-3_2.13-2+deb7u1_armhf.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/libx/libxml2/libxml2_2.8.0+dfsg1-7+wheezy2_armhf.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/c/curl/curl_7.26.0-1+wheezy11_armhf.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/c/curl/libcurl3_7.26.0-1+wheezy11_armhf.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/c/curl/libcurl3-gnutls_7.26.0-1+wheezy11_armhf.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/d/dbus/libdbus-1-3_1.6.8-1+deb7u5_armhf.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/f/flac/libflac8_1.2.1-6+deb7u1_armhf.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/j/jasper/libjasper1_1.900.1-13+deb7u2_armhf.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/n/nss/libnss3_3.14.5-1+deb7u3_armhf.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/liby/libyaml/libyaml-0-2_0.1.4-2+deb7u5_armhf.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/n/ntp/ntp_4.2.6.p5+dfsg-2+deb7u1_armhf.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/t/tzdata/tzdata_2014h-0wheezy1_all.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apt/apt-utils_0.9.7.9+rpi1+deb7u7_armhf.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/c/cpio/cpio_2.11+dfsg-0.1+deb7u1_armhf.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/r/rsyslog/rsyslog_5.8.11-3+deb7u2_armhf.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/w/wget/wget_1.13.4-3+deb7u2_armhf.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/m/mime-support/mime-support_3.52-1+deb7u1_all.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/o/openssl/openssl_1.0.1e-2+rvt+deb7u13_armhf.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/c/ca-certificates/ca-certificates_20130119+deb7u1_all.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/d/dbus/dbus_1.6.8-1+deb7u5_armhf.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/d/dbus/dbus-x11_1.6.8-1+deb7u5_armhf.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/d/dosfstools/dosfstools_3.0.13-1+rpi1_armhf.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/u/unzip/unzip_6.0-8+deb7u1_armhf.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/w/wpa/wpasupplicant_1.0-3+deb7u1_armhf.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/w/wpa/wpagui_1.0-3+deb7u1_armhf.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/x/xdg-utils/xdg-utils_1.1.0~rc1+git20111210-6+deb7u1_all.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/x/xorg-server/xserver-common_1.12.4-6+deb7u5_all.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/x/xorg-server/xserver-xorg-core_1.12.4-6+deb7u5_armhf.deb  Size mismatch
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Errors :/

Comment: It seems all requests causes a "Size mismatch", which I suspect is because the HTTP requests is returning something quite different than debian packages.  Try one of the URL's in your Pi's internet browser, and tell us what it returns.

Comment: I am sshing it :/ , I pinged the website and it responded

Comment: You could also use wget from the command line to see what the URL returns.  I would not trust a ping response in this situation.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/pgYAUuT2
I used a random url that had a failed to fetch
I got it, so why isnt my other packages installing?

Comment: According to your wget output, the size of the file is only 4835 bytes.  When I download it on my Pi, it is 1443354 bytes.  You should take a look at the downloaded file to see what it contains.

Comment: :O OMG, I nano'd into the .deb file and got this!
http://pastebin.com/uBpp1hRE

My router is messing with it somehow right? , Because according to the file it downloaded a warning page, how can I fix this?

Comment: What's also crazy is that I downloaded it on my main PC , And it was ~1.3mb

Comment: I have no idea what is causing this...  The closest thing I found when searching for keywords from your pastebin file, was a discussion about Norton ConnectSafe DNS servers.  https://community.norton.com/en/forums/disable-visit-anyway-link-connectsafe-alert-page

Comment: So, its based on DNS, Can i change my dns on my pi to maybe google servers?

Comment: Should I add my .list files back to /etc/apt/sources.list.d ?

Comment: I guess you should revert to your original setup.

Comment: Btw... Since this may be of interest to others having the same problem, you should answer your own question, and write a few words about what the problem was and how you solved it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a problem where I would get a "Size mismatch" message when installing a package, or performing an update, at first I thought it was a problem with my internet connection. I tried EVERYTHING, But all in all It was a problem with my router and my DNS, I simple went into the configuration of the pi's DNS

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

I then commented out the name server line/s and I added this

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
name server 8.8.4.4
```

Im aware that these are googles DNS, and now I can download stuff without it sending me to a security page! :) A big thank you to Werner Kvalem Vesterås for helping me out with this issue!

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below:

1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo rpi-update
4. sudo reboot -i

Then try this tutorial:
http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/

Comment: Does not work, im going to edit my post